# Disable Dropdown Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, dropdown

I know this very simple but I have been looking everywhere and tried some codes. Most of the codes I have searched were how to disable a drop down list which would send me to a series of select elements being disabled. What I want is to disable the whole button of the drop down that composes the drop down items. I've tried couldn't get the right codes for the program. I have a fiddle below. PS this is only an example fiddle that i want to disable.

I am trying this:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn-group').attr('disable', true)
});
```

full non-working code:-http://jsfiddle.net/ydxq1ue9/

Comment: Hi.  Unless I am missing it completely, I do not see a fiddle.

Comment: I'm sorry. I edited the question.

Comment: There was a reason why you couldn't post the link to jsfiddle. Please create a [mcve] and include the code in the question itself

Comment: You were almost there. You had to target the button inside the .btn-group.  Please take a look at this fiddle by Alive to Die below.  http://jsfiddle.net/9ohwkf0u/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Just target the `button` inside `.btn-group`.

Do like this:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn-group button').attr('disabled','disabled');
});
```

Running code:- http://jsfiddle.net/9ohwkf0u/

Comment: @Jane glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 1):

Add ID to the button:

```
  <button type="button" id="buttonID" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
```

and call this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#buttonID").prop("disabled", true);  
});
```

Comment: i tried adding id to button but i couldn't get it to work. thanks for the help!

Comment: I know you solved your problem, but here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/190664/

Answer (score 0):

You can add `disabled` class to the `<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle">` element, like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn-group button').addClass('disabled')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Action <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add class `disabled` to `button` tag. Like that:

```
$('.btn-group button').addClass('disabled')
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.btn-group').css({'pointer-events':'none', "opacity" : "0.5"});
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.